# Lazily-instantiated bean in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring framework, i got know default behavior Spring instantiates singleton beans at the time of startup, which is called eagerly instantiation. This is good behavior as it exposes any problems in instantiation of beans at start up only. But sometimes this behavior is not expected hence by addition lazy-init=”true” to the bean definition the instantiation can be postponed to first request.

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true">
<!-- no beans will be pre-instantiated... -->
</beans>
```

So would like to know what kind of scenarios we can go for Lazily-instantiated bean?. please explain with example.

Answer (score 2):

The first scenario that comes to my mind if when you have many beans to be instantiated and you have a system that should have a short start-up time (for example a web application that some time you need to re-deploy withouth stopping the server). With lazy initialization you can instantiate at start-up core beans while you can instantiate later beans that are less important or used less frequently.

Answer (score 1):

In general lazy-loading is always aking towards reducing resource requirements. @Giovanni's example of faster start-up and especially in the context of frequent redeploys is an excellent example in my view.

One thing to note, by default spring beans are singletons, if you make them lazy-loaded in highly concurrent environment, you might end-up in problems, note the section *Lazy instantiation: dangerous in multithreaded applications* from http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077568/learn-java/java-tip-67--lazy-instantiation.html